# React Native: Prettier stopped underlining in VSCode

Tags: react-native, vscode-extensions, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

I'm on VSCode version 1.78.1 and React Native version 0.69.10. I have the `ESLint` and `Prettier ESLint` VSCode extensions both enabled globally. Previously they were working as expected, underlining linting errors in red, prompting for correction, etc. I'm not sure when they stopped working, but now they don't underline anything. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling both extensions, restarting VSCode, etc. It may have happened when I was upgrading the React Native version, not sure.

Are there other troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this?

My `.prettierc.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
  bracketSameLine: true,
  bracketSpacing: false,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  tabWidth: 4,
};
```